# Rspec error undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to write a test case for the depot application. Below is the code

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :description, :image_url, :price, :title

 validates :title, :description, :image_url, :presence => true
 validates :price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01}

end
```

Test Case:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Product do
before :each do
    @product = Product.new "Title", "Description", "Image Url", "Price"
end

describe "#new" do
    it "takes four parameters and returns a product" do
        @product.should be_an_instance_of Product
    end
end

describe "#title" do
    it "returns the correct title" do
        @product.title.should eql "Title"
    end
end

describe "#description" do
    it "returns the correct description" do
        @product.description.should eql "Description"
    end
end

describe "#image_url" do
    it "returns the correct image_url" do
        @product.image_url.should eql "Image Url"
    end
end

describe "#price" do
    it "returns the correct price" do
        @product.price.should eql "Price"
    end
end

end
```

I am getting the errors

```
undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
```

and

```
ArgumentError:←[0m
1mwrong number of arguments (4 for 2)←[0m
 ./spec/product_spec.rb:5:in `new'←[0m
 ./spec/product_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) \
 in <top (required)>'" for all examples.
```

Please guide me on how to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
before :each do
   @product = Product.new(title: "Title", description: "Description", image_url: "Image Url", price: "Price")
end
```

Try [Michael Hartl's](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) awesome tutorial

Comment: Is there a way for testing the price numericality validation as written in model.

Comment: Sure. You can set the price to be something invalid (e.g. -5, dog, etc) and then say `@product.should_not be_valid` and `@product.should have(1).error_on(:price)`

Comment: How and where to set that invalid price ?

Comment: You would probably want a test case for ensuring price is a valid numeral. Inside your describe price block write a new case (something like it "should be a valid numeral"). Since you are constructing a valid product in your `before(:each)` block, you just need to now make this invalid e.g. `@product.price = -5` and then try the assertions I mentioned above.